# Porque ocurre esto luego del while

Tags: c

Este es el problema:
Confeccionar un programa que permita el ingreso de 6 ternas de valores enteros.
a. de cada terna informar el mayor valor y su orden en la terna.
b. de cada terna informar cuantos valores son múltiplos de 7.
c. de las 6 ternas determinar e informar el promedio de los primeros valores de cada una.

Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int ternas,n1,n2,n3,orden=0,mult7=0,n1p=0,mayor,n1t;

    ternas=0;

    printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el tercer numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n3);
    fflush(stdin);

    while(ternas!=6)
    {
        if(n1>=n2&&n1>=n3)
        {
            orden=1;
            mayor=n1;
        }
        else if(n2>=n1&&n2>=n3)
        {
            orden=2;
            mayor=n2;
        }
        else if(n3>=n1&&n3>=n2)introducir el código aquí
        {
            orden=3;
            mayor=n3;
        }
        if(n1%7==0)
        {
            mult7++;
        }
        if(n2%7==0)
        {
            mult7++;
        }
        if(n3%7==0)
        {
            mult7++;
        }
        ternas++;
        printf("El numero mayor es: %d, con orden %d\n",mayor,orden);
        printf("Cantidad de numeros multiplos de 7: %d\n",mult7);
        printf("\n");
        mult7=0;
        n1t=n1t+n1;

        printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingrese el segundo numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Ingrese el tercer numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&n3);
        fflush(stdin);

    }
    n1p=n1t/6;
    printf("El promedio de los primeros numeros de cada terna es: %d",n1p);

    return 0;
}
```

Resumen: Quiero que solo se muestre el ingreso de los 3 números 6 veces pero lo hace una vez mas de la necesaria:

Comment: Del 0 al 6 se harán 7 repeticiones, la primera cuando `ternas=0`, luego `ternas=1`, hasta ahí van dos, como vez se repetirá n+1 veces si lo inicializas en 0. Puedes inicializar `ternas=1` o hacer `while(ternas<6)`, ya que `6<6` es False

Answer (score 0):

Simplificando mucho el código para entenderlo mejor, obtienes algo como esto:

```
int main(){
    int ternas = 0;
    pedirNumeros(); 
    
    while(ternas != 6){
        ternas++;
        pedirNumeros();
    }
}
```

Si sigues la ejecución, verás por qué los números se piden 6 veces.

```
int main(){
    int ternas = 0;
    pedirNumeros(); // primera vez
    
    while(ternas != 6){
        ternas++; // ternas = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        pedirNumeros(); // 2ª vez, 3ª, 4ª, 5ª, 6ª, 7ª
    }
}
```

El ciclo se ejecuta 6 veces como corresponde. El inconveniente es que en total la pides los números 7 veces.

Para resolverlo, deberías quitar un ciclo o no pedir los números fuera del ciclo, con eso sería suficiente para que se pidan 6 veces.

Una posible solución (simplificada):

```
int main(){
    int ternas = 0,n1,n2,n3, ...;

    while(ternas != 6){
        pedirNumeros();

        if(n1>=n2&&n1>=n3)
        {
            orden=1;
            mayor=n1;
        }
        ...

        printf("El numero mayor es: %d, con orden %d\n",mayor,orden);
        ...

        ternas++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clásico error [off-by-one](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Comment: Al ser nuevo en esta pagina no supe usarla muy bien, por lo que me olvide aclarar que ya había probado esas dos opciones. Al sacar la ultima pedida de números del ciclo solo usa los primeros dígitos ingresados. Por lo que repite lo mismo 6 veces sin volver a pedir datos. Y si en su lugar lo coloco como menor o menor igual pide los numeros mas de 6 veces y en la ultima no toma en cuenta los if